# Git: add remote repo and only download diffs?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo on my local machine, pointing at GitHub.  I have copied all the files onto a server using FTP, and am running the site successfully on the server (it's a Django app).

Now I want to connect the remote server to the GitHub repo. The aim is that when I make changes locally, I can push them to GitHub and git pull them onto the remote server, rather than copying them across via FTP, which is a bit painful (and also could lead to the remote server gradually getting out of sync with the GitHub repo).

I have done this on the remote server:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/myrepo
```

Now if I do `git status` on the remote server, it tells me all the files on the remote server are untracked, 100% of them.

Ideally, the next step would be for me to pull from GitHub onto the remote server, then reconcile any differences.

However, I'm nervous about doing this in case it overwrites files on the remote server that turn out to be important config differences and the site stops working.

Is there any way I can "pull" the repo from GitHub without overwriting any local files that differ?

I realise I shouldn't have got into this mess in the first place - next time I'll work with Git from the start.

Comment: have you done any changes on your remote server ?

Comment: @Tajinder I think so, yes, but I don't know exactly what - so I'm nervous about overwriting everything.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the solution.
create a new project directory on your remote server

```
git clone https://github.com/myrepo
```

before doing the above step, make sure that you have committed all changes from your local system and is updated on repo.

now access this new project folder, and change the configuration (if required) and then divert your request inflow from your running project 
to this new project folder.

if everything seems fine, then continue with this new project folder, and remove the old project which was running earlier.

or if you are finding this inappropriate,
then create a copy for your project folder

```
cp -r your_project_folder  your_project_folder_new
```

and do

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/myrepo
```

which you have performed in your running project folder

and now you have full freedom to do anything with your files, 
now you can do

```
git pull
```

without worrying about the loss of code or anything.

and if you want to check the differences between the two folders then

```
diff -bur folder1/ folder2/
```